# Transit visa to re-check luggage in Frankfurt (different airlines)

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, fra

I'm a Colombian and I'll be traveling from Turkey to Colombia connecting in Frankfurt. First leg (IST-FRA) with Turkish airlines and second (FRA-BOG) with Lufthansa. Do I need to re-check my bags in Frankfurt? If so, do I need a transit visa to do so? Normally Colombians do not need transit visa at Frankfurt, but if I have to recheck my bags would I have to go through passport control? Many thanks.

Comment: You probably don't need to recheck your bags.  Ask the airline to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If your two legs are on seperate tickets, then the answer is *yes*: you will need to recheck your bags and need to have clearance to enter the country in this case.

If you booked both legs on the same ticket, then you should be able to stay in the international area of the FRA airport without re-checking. There will also be no passport check necessary in this case. However, note that the international area of Franfurt Airport closes over night. So if your fligth to BOG is at 6am, and you arrive at, say 6pm the day beforehand, you will need a visa to enter Germany. Also, double-check with your check-in agent in IST that (s)he printed "BOG" as final designation onto your luggage tag.

Even if your both legs are not booked onto the same ticket, you may be able to convince the check-in agent at IST straight to BOG as Turkish Airlines and Lufthansa most likely have an interlining agreement. In that case, you don't need a visa to enter Germany. *However*, it is not advisable to rely on this possibility, as sometimes gate agents refuse to do so.